# Switching Fragment from Onclick event from listview

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a fragment which has a listview, I use a separate baseadapter class to populate the listview with a layout from xml. I need to switch to a different Fragment when the user clicks a certain image in the listview. when i set up the onclick listener for that image i cant seem to use the getSupportFragmentManager() method inside the onclick. How can i achieve this?

```
      holder.userpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(" ", " value " + obj.get(position).get_post_id());
                final FragmentTransaction ft2 =  this.   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
             bundle.putInt("pk", value);
             bundle.putInt(" ", value);
                 ProfileFrag fragment2 = new   ProfileFrag ();
                 fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
                 ft2.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                 ft2.replace(R.id.fragment_swap,fragment2); 
                 ft2.addToBackStack(null);
                 ft2.commit(); 




             }
         });
```

Comment: paste some code please !

Answer (score 0):

You can accept a FragmentActivity (or ActionBarActivity) in the constructor of your BaseAdapter, save it as a field, and call the method on that field.

Comment: i passed the activity to the basedapater by  getting the activity using getActivity(). then i created a Activity variable in the baseadapter and tired this.activity but still didn't work

Comment: if you write this.activity inside the onClick method, it will not work because `this` is here the anonymous OnClickListener. Just write activity.getSupportFragmentManager()...

Comment: Did you find a solution i have the same issue! Any code to help?

Answer (score 0):

Use your Fragments name while calling getSupportFragmentManager()

```
YourFragmentName.this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```